# How to prevent optimization on a class field in C#

Tags: c#, optimization

I have built an abstract class that is used to handle command line options for our products.

One need only to create a class inheriting from AbstractOptions, fill it with decorated fields and call the inherited Parse(args) method to have it automatically filled through reflection with values from the command line. Values that were not found on the command line retain their current (default) values.

Then, the application needs only to check the option fields to get their value. The AbstractOptions class provides more features, like help output, etc, but it is beside the point.

Short example:

```
public class SignalOptions: AbstractOptions
{
    [Option("-i, --iterations", "Number of iterations (0 = infinite).")]
    volatile public int NumberOfIterations;

    [Option("-s, --silent", "Silent mode, only display final results.")]
    volatile public bool Silent;

    [Option("-w, --zwindow", "Window size for z-score analysis.")]
    volatile public int ZWindow = 7;

    [Option("-a, --zalert", "z-score value to consider as peak.")]
    public double ZAlert = 2.1;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var opts = new SignalOptions();
    opts.Parse(args)

    // If optimizations are turned off, SILENT will be written or not 
    // followind presence or absence of the --silent switch on the command line.
    // If optimizations are turned on, SILENT will never be written.
    // The reflection part is working fine. I suspect the problem is that
    // the compiler of the jitter having never found this set anywhere simply inlines
    // the value 'false' inthe if, because when I step on it, it shows me the value as 
    // true or false, but has the same behavior no matter what value opts.Silence has.
    if( opts.Silent )
        Console.Writeline("SILENT");
}
```

Now, the problem I have is that since the compiler does not find any code actually changing the values of the SignalOptions class, it simply inlines the values where they are used in the code. I have circumvent the issue by requiring that all 'option' fields in the class be volatile, so no optimization is applied, and it works fine, but unfortunately the volatile keyword is not valid on a double.

I have spent much time on the net trying to find a workaround, without success. Is there anyway to either prevent optimizations on the fields or otherwise fool the compiler/jitter into thinking they are used at runtime?

I also would like to put as less as possible the onus on the calling application.

Thanks

Comment: I strongly suspect you've misdiagnosed the issue. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: How would the compiler know if a public field of a public class is used? it could be used in an assembly that's not a part of the current build

Comment: Seconding that I do not believe the issue is what you describe ("inlines the values"). The compiler would only do that for `const` - otherwise `ldfld` is used, and the JIT is not going to worry overly about "is this assigned elsewhere". The only things that might affect this are obfuscators and full linkers (like AOT in Mono). Incidentally, properties would be far preferable to fields here, IMO.

Comment: Also: `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` is not valid on fields, so I doubt that is your real code

Comment: I have added more behavior comment in the code sample. I don't know why or how the compiler/jitter makes assumptions. All I see is what the debugger shows me, and that is no matter if the value is true or false, it will simply not perform the true part of the if no matter value in opts.Silent if optimizations are enabled but will behave correctly if i disable them.

Comment: @MarcGravell you are correct, the statement does not work or even compile for that matter, I had pasted in there to mention that I have tried this avenue (without success) but I forgot to remove it when I pasted the code here. I'll remove it.

Comment: What the hell is `volatile` doing there? Like Eric Lippert said, if you are using `volatile`, you are probably using it wrong.

Comment: Well I could post Parse() and all methods that go with it, but that would be rather voluminous and it is not the problem. Parse() works fine, the values a read fine, the debugger sees the good values... It's just that although after parsing opts.Silent is true(confirmed by debugger and watch) the code behave as if it is still false, and the same goes for the other variables. Well, this is no longer the behavior since I mark them as volatile, but it is when I remove it. Everything would be fine if it would also be allowed on doubles...

Comment: @leppie volatile instructs the compiler to make no assumptions on the content of the variable as it might be changed by another thread at anytime (thus disabling some optimizations on it).

Comment: @user611710: And there is your mistake. I bet you only have a single thread running, making this assumption pointless :) (Unless for some absurd reason you have `Parse` running as a thread).

Comment: @user611710 "everything would be fine"... wait; your claim is that this doesn't work even for the `bool` one, no? Your sample is for the `bool` one... so: what is failing? the `bool` or the `double`?

Comment: But to emphasise: "I don't know why or how the compiler/jitter makes assumptions." - simple: it doesn't.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `volatile` didn't fix your problem, but just masked it. You clearly do something horribly wrong in `opts.Parse` but without the relevant code, we can't tell you what.

Comment: just use [Mono.Options](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Options/Mono.Options/Options.cs)

Comment: Your code (the one you haven’t posted!) is almost comically wrong. This is why it’s important that you post *all* the relevant code. Questions like this just waste everybody’s time.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I wonder how you can judge that is comical if you haven't seen it. If you don't know the answer to the question "How to prevent optimization on a class field in C#", please feel free to not waste your time with it.

Comment: Don't worry, I won't. I just wanted to explain my downvote.

Comment: @user611710: I'm still not seeing a short but *complete* example which demonstrates the problem...

Comment: @JonSkeet Truly sorry, no longer access to work computer, i will have to post a follow up later. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: @Henk The code that he didn't post, that would be crucial to answering the question.

Comment: I'm on the edge of my seat waiting for this code!

Comment: @user611710: When will you post the code? There are several of us waiting patiently for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a local copy here with `Parse` written as the rather opaque:

```
public void Parse(string[] args)
{    // deliberately opaque, not that it would make any difference
    string fieldName = (new string('S', 1) + "ilentX").Substring(0, 6);
    GetType().GetField(fieldName).SetValue(this, true);
}
```

It works fine. I do not believe the problem is what you think it is.

Comment: As I said, reflection is working fine. That is not the issue. The issue is that although the reflected value is now set to the expected value, the remaining application code does not even read the value, unless, of course, optimizations are disabled.

Comment: @user611710 which optimizations are you disabling, exactly *how*? We need to understand **exactly** what you are seeing... But! Removing a branch by detecting a field is never assigned is *not* something that is done AFAIK. I should say: I'm using a release/optimized build to test here, both inside and outside the debugger.

Comment: I have not figured out why but can't reproduce the problem out of the actual application. Thanks everyone for the time. I don't know how to mark the question as obsolete or not good or otherwise, so i checked this answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess:

`Parse` is running in a separate thread, but as your synchronization is somehow flawed, this makes the rest of code run without having the values set already.

This would also explain why you are seeing the correct values in the debugger.

**Update (opinionated):**

Having `Parse` run in a separate thread is very weird, and should be considered a design flaw. Sounds like someone was thinking 'Reflection is slow, let's put it in a separate thread'.

Comment: Indeed, a timing issue making this a heisenbug would be a possible cause - a bit hard to say without `Parse`, but...

Comment: ok, maybe i don't explain myself properly. 1) There is only one thread, it's a simple console application. 2) If I use the volatile keyword everything works fine in any situation. 3) If I remove volatile keyword I need to disable optimizations for it to work 4) I disable optimizations by unchecking the Optimize code check box in project built options.

Comment: @user611710 can you **please** show a complete sample that actually shows the issue you are describing? It doesn't need to use the actual `Parse` code (see my example, for illustration). If you can show a basic standalone example that illustrates this, we'll leap at it with all force. My guess is that you'll *struggle* to reproduce this in a simple example, and that gradually/carefully making the simple example into your real code will show exactly where the **real** problem is.

Comment: If the app is so simple, just post the contents of Parse here or on pastebin.org

Comment: @user611710 also, note I have tried with/without optimizations, and with/without `volatile`

Comment: @user611710: Just for kicks, add `Thread.Sleep(2000)` after the call to `Parse` and see if the issue is still there.